# Cocoapods: Class XX is implemented in both

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have bunch of such errors using Firebase in my target:

> objc[13653]: Class FIRAAppEnvironmentUtil is implemented in both
>   /Users/.../DataController.framework/DataController (0x10b2fe1f8) and
>   /Users/.../MyApp.app/MyApp (0x1088b5d48). One of the two will be used.
>   Which one is undefined.

I have my application and several targets (some logic was moved to separate targets to maintain application more easily).

App structure:

- MyApp <- application
- DataController <- app's target
- <...> <- another targets

I'm using Pods, example Podfile I'm using:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Test'
end

target 'DataController' do
    pod 'Firebase', '~> 3.7.1'
end
```

In my investigations I've found that *Pods-MyApp.debug.xcconfig* contains paths to ALL frameworks inside `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` (not only to owns frameworks, but also paths to frameworks for all targets). I don't know if it is correct, maybe that information can help.

**I've tried:**

- Remove `Pods` directory
- Remove `.xcworkspace` file
- Install latest CocoaPods (1.2.0.beta.1)

Nothing helped, what else I can try? That problem is only with Firebase as I see in logs, I have other Objective-C pods, but there is no such problem with them. I'm absolutely sure that Firebase module is not duplicated in main application target.

Comment: did you also try removing your Derived Data folder (e.g. `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, yes I've tried

Comment: @Vasily did you ever solve this?

Comment: Facing same errror in salesforce mobile sdk and service cloud sdk